# noUiSlider -> use value as form input

Tags: javascript, nouislider

I'm using the noUiSlider and I'm trying to use the slider value as a form input value (to send it in a working form).
I've tried various examples that I could find on stack overflow, but nothing seems to work.
This is my slider script:

```
<script>
var slider = $('#slider');
noUiSlider.create(slider[0], {
    start: [2000],
    range: { min: 2000, max: 10000 },
  step: 500,
  tooltips: true,
  connect: [true, false],
});
</script>
```

Maybe there's a hint in there why the codes I find aren't working. Because to initiate the slider I somewhere found the code `var slider = $('#slider');` to work for me and not `var slider = document.getElementById('slider');` as shown in most examples and documentation.

I would appreciate a very simple solution/explanation, as I actually don't know javascript at all...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

noUIslider does not create an html input so I can see 2 easy options.

1- Add a hidden input in your form that will contain the slider value and will be updated each time slider change event is triggered.

```
<form>
 <div id="slider"></div>
 <input id="sliderValueInput" type="hidden" value=""> 
</form>

<script>
var slider = noUiSlider.create($("#slider")[0], {
    start: [2000],
    range: { min: 2000, max: 10000 },
  step: 500,
  tooltips: true,
  connect: [true, false],
});

//define initial hidden input value with slider value
$("#sliderValueInput").val(slider.get());

//update hidden input value on slider change
slider.on("change", function() {
    $("#sliderValueInput").val(slider.get());
});
</script>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mxXYBK

2- Handle your form post data manually at submit with an AJAX request for instance. Demo can be provided if needed...

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this doesn't seem to work for me. I have changed type="hidden" to "text" to see if the value shows, but it doesn't. It's driving me crazy!

Comment: Provide your code if you want to have a personalized working demo

Comment: That would be great! Basically it's: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RMQddN

Comment: oh, sorry, I've never used codepen before, plus I thought you only needed to see what is inside my html for reference. I'll import the files and add a new comment then.